# PHP - cURL. Error 501 Not Implemented

Tags: php, curl

I getting error upon submitting a post request using cURL. So far i have this code:

```
$login_url = 'http://192.168.1.1/login';

$postArr = array(
    'username'=>'username',
    'password'=>'password',
    'dst' => base_url().'login/home'
);
$this->curlPost($login_url, $postArr);



function curlPost($url, $data){
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);

        echo 'using curl --- '.$url.'<br />';
        var_dump($server_output);
}
```

Basically, this code should do POST username and password to specific url, but unfortunately it is returning "Error 501: Not Implemented" my server is wamp. Anyone have idea what is causing this issue? Thanks

Comment: ok just a typo error, will edit it, this code is from codeigniter

Comment: The error is served by the script you call. So you should check if the script works correctly.